# Last American soldier leaving Afghanistan, was there a deal from American govt with Taliban to hold fire

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, afghanistan, taliban

Per the news the last American soldier boarded the flight showing his back to the Talibans, they could have fired shots since the last flight of American soldiers out numbered the Taliban forces. Also no aircrafts were brought down during this process. Is it that American diplomacy and Talibans had made a deal?

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/afghanistan-troops-withdrawal-last-american-soldier-leave-chris-donahue/

Comment: Why would they want to shoot the last soldiers leaving the country?

Comment: I mean their agenda was to hurt as many Americans as possible, no? The very idea of Taliban is to oppose the West

Comment: Yeah, but the last thing they want is to provide some excuse for the "damned infidel Americans" to turn around and come back.  Its better for them to just let the soldiers leave largely unmolested, than to kill any and possibly provoke retaliation.

Comment: Good point, with this I assume that there was no last minute deal done

Comment: Why would they risk provoking the US when the US is doing exactly what they want (leaving)?

Comment: @Up-In-Air "I mean their agenda was to hurt as many Americans as possible, no?" No, their agenda was to gain back control of Afghanistan, and get rid of the foreign invaders. Restarting a war with the foreign invaders would have worked against that goal.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Why did the Taliban not conquer the airport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68410).  Look at all the comments, they pretty much match responses on that other question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if they had killed the last 100 US soldiers trying to leave, 50,000 would have come back by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It was the [Doha agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doha_Agreement_(2020)) signed by Trump in 2020. Since then the Taliban attacked Afghan government positions, but they didn't attack US soldiers.